# Change struct field in function or return the value

Tags: go

In the end, this question will surely depend on personal preferences. Nevertheless, I would like to dare an attempt to find out which style is the preferred one.

I have recently noticed inconsistencies in my code. I have a struct with some fields. The question now is what is the idiomatic way to edit this field when I need to call a function to get the value I want to set. Do I set the value inside the function, or do I return it and set it in my calling function?

```
type SuperStruct struct {
    OneValue     string
    AnotherValue string
}

func (s *SuperStruct) makeAnotherValue() {
    s.AnotherValue = "Hello there"
}

func main() {
    superStruct := SuperStruct{}
    superStruct.makeAnotherValue()
}
```

or (with the same struct)

```
func (s *SuperStruct) makeAnotherValue() string {
    return "Hello there"
}

func main() {
    superStruct := SuperStruct{}
    superStruct.AnotherValue = superStruct.makeAnotherValue()
}
```

I know that there are cases where only one of these ways makes sense. But I often find myself in a situation where both are possible. I guess the second way would allow for better guarding, but sometimes that's not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idiomatic go way would be to remove your function entirely:

```
func main() {
    superStruct := SuperStruct{AnotherValue:"Hello there"}
}
```

or

```
func main() {
    superStruct := SuperStruct{}
    ...
    superStruct.AnotherValue = "Hello there"
}
```

Don't build getters/setters/create functions unless they are absolutely necessary, just do the work required. If you're just setting a simple field, you don't need a factory to make the field value in most cases. If you think the function is necessary, it would need to be a lot more complex than this (at least a few lines) and would typically be called NewAnotherValue and not attached to the parent struct.

Every indirection through another function/struct makes the code harder to follow.

Comment: Perhaps the example was a bit less. It's about complex tasks, rather than just setting a value. Query API, IO accesses or complex collection operations.

Comment: Post the actual code if you really feel stuck, but I think it's pretty straightforward in go style - avoid unecc. abstraction, use NewXXX to create new types where you want to wrap a complex setup, don't create type b inside a function on type a (you can, but there's no need to).